Testflight build behaving different than xcode build
whenever I test my app on Xcode it works perfectly. However, downloading an Xcode build, videos from both categories intermingle when another category is selected. This usually happens for the first few posts when switching categories with some appearing later on as well. I have tested multiple times on xcode and testflight and this issue only appears on the testflight builds. No matter what I do to separate the categories or if I use a @Published variable with @StateObject for the videos, nothing seems to change. Thanks for any help in advance!
enum Tab: String {
    case categoryOne
    case categoryTwo
    
    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .categoryOne:
            return "Category One"
        case .categoryTwo:
            return "Category Two"
        }
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tab = .categoryOne
    @State private var categoryOneVideos: [Video] = []
    @State private var categoryTwoVideos: [Video] = []
    @State private var isLoadingMore = false
    @State private var dataReloaded = false

    private func loadInitialVideos() {
        switch selectedTab {
        case .categoryOne:
            let allVideos = API.getVideos(category: .categoryOne)
            categoryOneVideos = allVideos
                .filter { video in
                    guard let _ = URL(string: video.url.absoluteString) else { return false }
                    return true
                }
                .map { $0 }
            
        case .categoryTwo:
            let allVideos = API.getVideos(category: .categoryTwo)
            categoryTwoVideos = allVideos
                .filter { video in
                    guard let _ = URL(string: video.url.absoluteString) else { return false }
                    return true
                }
                .map { $0 }
        }
        dataReloaded.toggle()
    }
    
    private func loadMoreVideos() async {
        guard !isLoadingMore else { return }
        isLoadingMore = true
        await Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            var newVideos: [Video] = []
            switch selectedTab {
            case .categoryOne:
                let currentIds = categoryOneVideos.map { $0.id }
                if let newMedia = API.getNextMedia(category: .categoryOne, hasSeen: currentIds) {
                    API.updateMedia(with: newMedia)
                    newVideos = API.getVideos(category: .categoryOne)
                        .filter { video in
                            guard let _ = URL(string: video.url.absoluteString) else { return false }
                            return true
                        }
                        .filter { !currentIds.contains($0.id) }
                }
                
            case .categoryTwo:
                let currentIds = categoryTwoVideos.map { $0.id }
                if let newMedia = API.getNextMedia(category: .categoryTwo, hasSeen: currentIds) {
                    API.updateMedia(with: newMedia)
                    newVideos = API.getVideos(category: .categoryTwo)
                        .filter { video in
                            guard let _ = URL(string: video.url.absoluteString) else { return false }
                            return true
                        }
                        .filter { !currentIds.contains($0.id) }
                }
            }
            
            await MainActor.run {
                if selectedTab == .categoryOne {
                    categoryOneVideos.append(contentsOf: newVideos)
                } else {
                    categoryTwoVideos.append(contentsOf: newVideos)
                }
                isLoadingMore = false
            }
        }
    }
}

.onChange(of: selectedTab) { _ in
                        let impactMed = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium)
                        impactMed.impactOccurred()
                        Task {
                            loadMoreVideos()
                            let savedIndex = restoreScrollPosition()
                            currentIndex = savedIndex
                            proxy.scrollTo(currentIndex, anchor: .top)
                            dataReloaded.toggle()
                        }
                    }


You are likely dealing with race conditions or memory leaking. You seem to be haphazardly mixing different types of asynchronous work

Replace onChange, Task and MainActor.run with simply .task(id: index) and inside it await a result from your async func that you set on a state

Thanks, implementing those changes works at xcode but not on testflight. Any thoughts?

This might happen when you have not used lazy component while loading remote content. Try replacing your stack to LazyVStack/LazyHStack.
